# Turning on SEND_TIME_FILTERING business rule

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

How do I turn this on? I cannot find these in the admin settings. Is this a special feature, that I would need to contact ET for?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, business rules have to be enabled by SFMC Support.

Usually doesn't take too long, especially if you know the internal name of the rule.